# 500 - Server Error : Using expressjs to upload user registration. I can't figure out what is causing this error using express.Router to handle it

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, npm, handlebars.js

I am using .env to connect to MYSQL and the connection works fine. My views are working as well, but the router.post..., is not working. This is a simple registration and login app that I am trying to create. I done this in a different method with all the database query in the app.js file which worked fine. but with this setup convention its not working.The problem is with the database query in the express.router function auth.js is in a folder : routes/auth.js, I have only two files the app.js and the auth.js

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({ defaultLayout: 'main' });
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
var route = require('./routes/auth');
var app = express();

//diable metadata header response
app.disable('x-powered-by');

//app template configuration setup
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

//static resources configuration
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//routing modulation
app.use('/', route);
app.use('about', route);
app.use('login', route);
app.use('register', route);
app.use('upload', route);



//file upload config
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(express.static('upload'));

//forn encoding
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//app port for viewing
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);


//custom 404 page
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404);
    res.render('404');
});

//custom 500 page
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500);
    res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), (req, res) => {
    console.log('Express started on localhost:' +
        app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});

module.exports = app;
```

auth.js : to handle the query to MYSQL

```
var express = require('express');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var fortune = require('../lib/fortune');
var db = require('../controllers/database');
var router = express.Router();


// define the home page route
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});


//About Page route
router.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about', { fortune: fortune.getFortune });
});

//middleware registration page route
router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register');
});

router.post('/register',  (req, res) => {

    var { firstName, lastName, email, password, passwordConfirm } = req.body;

    db.query('SELECT email FROM registration WHERE email = ?', [email], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        if (results.length > 0) {
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'That email is already in use'
            })
        }
        else if (password !== passwordConfirm) {
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'Passwords do not match'
            })
        }
    });

    let hashedPwd = bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    console.log(hashedPwd);


    db.query('INSERT INTO registration SET ? ',  { firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email, password: hashedPwd }, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(results);
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'User registered'
            });
        }
    });

    
});


router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

register.handlebars

```
<form class="row g-3" role="form" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/register">
    <div class="col-12">
        <label for="inputAddress" class="form-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Jane" name="firstName">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <label for="inputAddress" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Doe" name="lastName">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="janedoe@mail" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Confim Password" name="passwordConfirm">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </div>
    {{#if message}}
    <h4 class="alert alert-danger mt-4">{{message}}</h4>
    {{/if}}
</form>
```

Comment: Do you receive some message at 500 at server (not the response, the real error)? As the route has lot of code, would be good to understand where the error really happens.

Comment: yes. on the local server. when I go to the register page to register as a user i get the 500 - server error...